# Extending an Animated Vector Flow from Two to Three Dimensions

Tags: manipulate

I found some code for animating a two-dimensional vector flow on stackexchange.  Unfortunately, I can't find the original post so I can't credit the author.  I have modified the code for my purposes below.

In any case, I would like to take this code and extend it up to an animation of a three-dimensional vector flow.  In others words, I’d like to make the same animation but with a 3D vector field.

I think this would be great to share with my multivariable calculus students.

```
Manipulate[
 
 Graphics[{Thickness[0.005], CapForm["Round"], lines[i]}, 
  Background -> White, PlotRange -> 10],
 {{i, 1, ""}, 1, Infinity, 1, ControlType -> Trigger, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"TriggerButton", "PauseButton"}},
 
 Initialization :> (
   plot = 
    StreamPlot[{-y, Sin[x] x}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
     StreamPoints -> 12];
   splines = Cases[plot, Arrow[data_] :> BSplineFunction[data], -1];
   r = Range[0, 1, 0.09];
   cols = Opacity[#, Blue] & /@ r;
   lines[i_] := 
    Map[Line[# /@ r, VertexColors -> RotateRight[cols, i]] &, 
     splines];), Paneled -> False]
```

A visual is shown below.

[image]

I am having a hard time rotating the vertex colors in 3D, perhaps because I'm having a hard time understanding splines in 3D?  Any ideas?  I would like to be able to rotate the 3d graphic while it’s flowing.

For example, how would I create the same animated effect for

```
StreamPlot3D[{-y, Sin[x] x, x}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 
  10}]
```

while preserving the ability to rotate the 3D graphic without causing the animation to stop or hesitate.

Comment: Please post a 3D version of the static stream plot.

Comment: @cvgmt  Updated.  This is more of a general-purpose tool, but edited the post to provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Dynamic change the position of `Arrowheads`.

```
Manipulate[
 StreamPlot3D[{-y, Sin[x] x, x}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 
    10}, StreamMarkers -> "Arrow"] /. 
  Arrow[b_] -> {Arrowheads[{{.025, t}}], Arrow[b]}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

- We can also rewrite the original 2D case to 3D case.
- Add `StreamMarkers -> "Arrow"`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
plot = StreamPlot3D[{-y, Sin[x] x, x}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
    10}, {z, -10, 10}, StreamMarkers -> "Arrow", StreamPoints -> 12];
splines = Cases[plot, Arrow[data_] :> BSplineFunction[data], -1];
r = Range[0, 1, 0.09];
cols = Opacity[#, Blue] & /@ r;
lines[i_] := 
  Map[Line[# /@ r, VertexColors -> RotateRight[cols, i]] &, splines];
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.005], CapForm["Round"], lines[i]}, 
  Background -> White, PlotRange -> 10], {{i, 1, ""}, 1, Infinity, 1, 
  ControlType -> Trigger, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"TriggerButton", "PauseButton"}}, 
 Paneled -> False]
```

[image]